# Error sending eMail with attachment via cronjob, but works in bash

Tags: cron

I have a strange problem. I use the following command line to send an eMail with attachment via console:

```
/usr/bin/mutt -s "AwStats $(date +%d.%m.%Y)" -a /path/to/file myemail@gmail.com < /dev/null
```

Works like a charm.

But I want it sent via cron, so I created this cronjob:

```
@daily root /usr/bin/mutt -s "AwStats $(date +%d.%m.%Y)" -a /path/to/file myemail@gmail.com < /dev/null
```

The cronjob does get executed, but fails with this error message:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I have no idea why. Would anyone be able to help? Thank you VERY much in advance!

Kind regards
-A

Answer (score 5):

in crontab you need to escape `%`'s with a `\` so

```
@daily root /usr/bin/mutt -s "AwStats $(date +\%d.\%m.\%Y)" -a /path/to/file myemail@gmail.com < /dev/null
```

will probably fix the problem for you.

Comment: Great, lain! Works like a charm now - Thank you **very, very much** for your help!!

Comment: mark this solution as the correct on. hit the check mark

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Iain's answer, since cron is not bash you will probably also need to change

```
$(date +\%d.\%m.\%Y)
```

to be

```
`date +\%d.\%m.\%Y`
```

Or you could put all of your original job in a bash script and just call the script instead.